# uniqueidentifier Equivalent DataType In C#

Tags: c#, sql, c#-3.0

what is uniqueidentifier (Sql server 2005) equivalent in C# 3.5 datatype ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It should be [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey1zx63%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [Nullable<Guid>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

System.Guid.NewGuid()

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Guid

Example :

```
    public string CustID { get; set; }

    public System.Guid ActivationCode { get; set;}
```